# No assets folder available in Robolectric test

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have been struggling for a while, with the following. In a Robolectric unit test, I use a file in the assets folder to read as mock input. This used to work fine, until a few months ago. I see that the assets folder is not included in the `app/build/intermediates` folder. I found a work around by pointing the code to the assets folder, hard-coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In another project, created recently, I found that there is an assets folder in the build dir structure. After experimenting with various parameters, I found that the bug (if it's a bug) is in the Android version or build tools version. Upgrading from

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
   ...
```

to

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
   ...
```

resolved the issue.